# Magento 2.4.3 not generating *.min.js files

Tags: javascript, magento2.4.3, production-mode

i am working a magento 2.4.3 the config (dev/js/minify_files) is set to 1. When i try to run the command

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

The script exit with the following error

```
Error happened during deploy process: The contents from the "/var/www/vhosts/{domain}/httpdocs/development/shop/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/vhosts/{domain}/httpdocs/development/shop/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I see the magento is not generating minified version of the Javascripts files. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find finally. If you are using advanced JS bundling then js merge and js bundling should be off otherwise it will throw this error